# FPGA HDMI Video Lag tester doesn't display on FPV goggles

Tags: fpga, hdmi

I've forked this [video lag tester](https://github.com/pthalin/video_lag_tester) Verilog project, which is itself a port of the [time-sleuth](https://github.com/chriz2600/time-sleuth) project to the GOWIN Tang 4K FPGA. My intention is to build something that can test the input lag on [FPV goggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-mounted_display#Remote_control).

My issue is that the forked project worked fine on every PC monitor and TV I tested it on but refused to display on the 3 different FPV goggles I tested (blank display), even though I'm outputting a 720p60 RGB444 video which is compatible with all the goggles (because they work when connected to a PC with these settings).

Initially I suspected the issue might be that the goggles lacked backwards compatibility with DVI since I couldn't get them working when connected to the DVI port of a video card (via a DVI-HDMI adapter), but they worked fine on the HDMI port. Since the original code only did DVI over HDMI, I suspected this might be the issue and have since incorporated some code from this [hdl-util/hdmi](https://github.com/hdl-util/hdmi) project to do proper HDMI TERC4 encoding with preambles, data and video guards, etc. as well as sending AVI InfoFrame packets to the sink to communicate the source format. I've verified that these changes work fine on my monitors and TV, and even played around with various InfoFrame packet settings to verify that they are understood by the sinks, but the goggles still refused to work. I've also tried outputting the limited RGB range (16-235) to no avail.

I read somewhere that low power devices might disable their high-speed HDMI receivers until woken up to conserve power, and since the goggles are battery powered I started to investigate whether I need to send a CEC command to bring the goggles out of standby. But after hooking up the goggles to a Raspberry PI and using the [cec-ctl](https://www.mankier.com/1/cec-ctl) tool as well as using a logic analyzer on the CEC line via an HDMI breakout board I've come to the conclusion that they don't actually support CEC. It's also worth noting that I tried `ddcutil detect` to see if DDC commands were supported for bring the goggles out of standby and found no DDC support.

Finally, I've decoded the EDID from a pair of the goggles (SKY04X) to see if there was anything which stood out when compared to a regular LCD monitor and the only thing I noticed was the power management field missing the "Standby, Suspend" options:

```
Monitor #2 [Real-time 0x1100]
  Model name............... ITE6802
  Manufacturer............. ITE
  Plug and Play ID......... ITE6802
  Serial number............ 26625
  Manufacture date......... 2013, ISO week 0
  Filter driver............ None
  -------------------------
  EDID revision............ 1.3
  Input signal type........ Digital
  Color bit depth.......... Undefined
  Display type............. RGB color
  Screen size.............. 1150 x 650 mm (52.0 in)
  Power management......... Active off/sleep
  Extension blocs.......... 1 (CEA/CTA-EXT)
  -------------------------
  DDC/CI................... Not supported

Color characteristics
  Default color space...... Non-sRGB
  Display gamma............ 2.20
  Red chromaticity......... Rx 0.618 - Ry 0.351
  Green chromaticity....... Gx 0.280 - Gy 0.605
  Blue chromaticity........ Bx 0.152 - By 0.063
  White point (default).... Wx 0.313 - Wy 0.329
  Additional descriptors... None

Timing characteristics
  Horizontal scan range.... 15-80kHz
  Vertical scan range...... 48-122Hz
  Video bandwidth.......... 160MHz
  CVT standard............. Not supported
  GTF standard............. Not supported
  Additional descriptors... None
  Preferred timing......... Yes
  Native/preferred timing.. 1920x1080p at 60Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1920x1080" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
  Detailed timing #1....... 720x480p at 60Hz (4:3)
    Modeline............... "720x480" 27.000 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync

Standard timings supported

EIA/CEA/CTA-861 Information
  Revision number.......... 3
  IT underscan............. Not supported
  Basic audio.............. Supported
  YCbCr 4:4:4.............. Supported
  YCbCr 4:2:2.............. Supported
  Native formats........... 2
  Detailed timing #1....... 1280x720p at 60Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1280x720" 74.250 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
  Detailed timing #2....... 640x480p at 60Hz (4:3)
    Modeline............... "640x480" 25.180 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
  Detailed timing #3....... 720x480p at 60Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "720x480" 27.000 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync

CE video identifiers (VICs) - timing/formats supported
    1920 x 1080p at  60Hz - HDTV (16:9, 1:1) [Native]
    1280 x  720p at  60Hz - HDTV (16:9, 1:1)
    1280 x  720p at  50Hz - HDTV (16:9, 1:1)
     640 x  480p at  60Hz - Default (4:3, 1:1)
     720 x  480p at  60Hz - EDTV (4:3, 8:9)
     720 x  480p at  60Hz - EDTV (16:9, 32:27)
    NB: NTSC refresh rate = (Hz*1000)/1001

CE audio data (formats supported)
  LPCM    2-channel, 16/20/24 bit depths at 32/44/48 kHz

CE speaker allocation data
  Channel configuration.... 2.0
  Front left/right......... Yes
  Front LFE................ No
  Front center............. No
  Rear left/right.......... No
  Rear center.............. No
  Front left/right center.. No
  Rear left/right center... No
  Rear LFE................. No

CE vendor specific data (VSDB)
  IEEE registration number. 0x000C03
  CEC physical address..... 1.0.0.0
  Maximum TMDS clock....... 165MHz

Report information
  Date generated........... 10/08/2023
  Software revision........ 2.91.0.1043
  Data source.............. Real-time 0x1100
  Operating system......... 10.0.19045.2

Raw data
  00,FF,FF,FF,FF,FF,FF,00,26,85,02,68,01,68,00,00,00,17,01,03,80,73,41,78,2A,7C,11,9E,59,47,9B,27,
  10,50,54,00,00,00,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,02,3A,80,18,71,38,2D,40,58,2C,
  45,00,10,09,00,00,00,1E,8C,0A,D0,8A,20,E0,2D,10,10,3E,96,00,04,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,FC,00,49,
  54,45,36,38,30,32,0A,20,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,FD,00,30,7A,0F,50,10,00,0A,20,20,20,20,20,20,01,F3,
  02,03,19,72,46,90,04,13,01,02,03,23,09,07,07,83,01,00,00,65,03,0C,00,10,00,01,1D,00,72,51,D0,1E,
  20,6E,28,55,00,10,09,00,00,00,1E,D6,09,80,A0,20,E0,2D,10,10,60,A2,00,04,03,00,00,00,18,8C,0A,D0,
  8A,20,E0,2D,10,10,3E,96,00,10,09,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,7B
```

I would really appreciate a pointer to what I might be missing here.